# How do I get classes autoloaded in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are obviously some classes that are automatically loaded when I start "irb" using "rails c". So how do I ensure my own classes are loaded? Am I expected to use "require"?

I get "NameError: uninitialized constant" whenever I try to use my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes are included as part of the Rails app though the Gem bundle, or you're `require`-ing the classes elsewhere in the app, then they should be loaded along with the Rails app into the console.

If they're completely indepent of Rails (e.g. the Rails app doesn't load these classes), then you'll have to require them explicitly.